# How do I appropriately control for a limiting/maximum value in regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity

I have a dataset where one variable is limited by the value of another. It is a study of participants with a particular disease. By necessity, therefore, age of disease onset, *A*, can be no larger than age of registration into the study, *R*.

How do I control for (i.e. avoid confounding due to) the limiting value *R* when testing variables that may have an association with *A*?

For example, suppose we see that gender (*G*) is associated with *A*; in particular, females have significantly lower age of disease onset than males. But if there is a relationship between gender and age of registration (*R*) - imagine for example that young males are less likely to register into the study - then this could explain the observed association with *A*.

So we are actually interested in whether gender (*G*) is associated with age of onset (*A*) **after accounting for** the effect of different ages of registration (*R*).

My first thought would be to control for *R* in a linear model:

$A \sim G + R$

But since *A* is bounded by *R* this produces a funnel-shaped residual plot that suggests heteroscedasticity: [image: residuals]

This makes me think this model is not appropriate, but I'm not quite sure how to proceed from here. Is this a problem? (Is it also a problem that there will be some correlation between the two independent variables *R* and *G*?)

It seems like this situation, or slight variations on it, would be quite common. So I'm hoping that there is a well established solution that I am as yet unaware of.